how to use if Condition with plotshape
I want to plot - Rebuy only when its within buy state = ▲ and plot Resell only when Its in '▼' state. I want to plotshape "ReBUY" only if buy is true and if sell is true it should plotshape resell.
I tried to use if condition but Plotshape is not allowed under condition.
plotshape(buy, title='BUY ', text='▲', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#000c76, 0), textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title='SELL', text='▼', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#5f0039, 0), textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), size=size.tiny)

////

plotshape(buyj, title='BUY ', text='ReBUY', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(0, 113, 21), textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sellj, title='SELL', text='ReSELL', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.rgb(151, 0, 90), textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), size=size.tiny)
/////


You can use your condition in the series argument of the plotshape().
plotshape(your_buy_condition and buy, title='BUY ', text='▲', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#000c76, 0), textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(your_sell_condition and sell, title='SELL', text='▼', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#5f0039, 0), textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), size=size.tiny)


Thank you for reply.. but it didnt works as expected could you please help ?
